# How to report careers messages which sound suspiciously like recruiters?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I received a message on careers from someone about "positions we are working on for various top Ad Technology companies" in my city... "5 positions with 3 different companies in NYC for your review".

The message lists the name of the company that this person works for (which is halfway across the country), but not the name of any of the companies whose positions are listed.

What raises my suspicions more is that the email address given in the message is a Gmail address, and the top Google link for this person's email address is a blog post from a random developer out there decrying emails from recruiters with "exciting!" positions that give absolutely zero info about the company the position is for.

The email reads suspiciously like it's from the types of shady recruiters that Careers was designed to weed out.

I couldn't find any way within Careers to report a suspicious message - is this something that we should be able to do? Is this "employer" breaking some terms of the site? Or am I being uber-anal?

Comment: Do they want you to be someone like Kevin? http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Missing-Interview,-Infantile-Expectancies,--More.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is good. You might also e-mail the team via careers@stackoverflow.com