# Unaffiliated Recruiters Messaging SO members on SO Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page, offensive

Yes, this post is a dupe--here is the [antecedent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40064/how-to-report-careers-messages-which-sound-suspiciously-like-recruiters), or at least the one i know about.

That one appears to be from a different recruiter than mine; and my guess is that the SO Mods want to know about *each* instance of this sort of thing, and I assume this is the place to notify them.

I received this vague message from a recruiter whose also gave her [linkedin Profile](http://www.linkedin.com/in/RecruitingDiva) in the message:

> *I liked your profile and would love to see if you are interested in
>   exploring a couple of leadership roles, if there is a strong alignment
>   with your interests and the requirements.*

I replied and asked her which jobs she was talking about--"please give me the SO Careers ID, etc. so I can access them and let you know".

Her reply a few hours later ignored that request, and instead just asked me to send my CV to her email address (the domain is ***prompthire***). (I'm not sure what she thought that SO Careers page was that she landed on--the one with my name in large font at the top--apparently not my CV.)

I believe this is the sort of activity SO Careers intends to exclude, if not, I can live with it, though i would just like to know if I'm likely to receive messages of this type again.

To discourage this sort of thing generally, i include a *no recruiters* on my Profile. Still, maybe this breach of the Rules should be excused in situations where the Profile in question is just so damn good that recruiters can't resist, but that's clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We do not want recruiters contacting you without letting you know the specific position/company they are representing.  We haven't seen wide spread abuse of this so far, but are working on ways to bring the number of bad actors down.

In the meantime, it is helpful when you point out these cases so we can follow up with the recruiter and let them know our policy.

Comment: For those unaware: Will Cole is a member of the Careers 2.0 team.